# Building links towards Category Pages?

Tags: seo, google, links, link-building

I am current building some links and I want to get the best results out of it. I have had links towards my homepage, as well as detail page but not many are towards my category page. I assume having links towards category pages are one way to enhance the recognition of website by Google (showing category pages are useful to people as well).

Is this as useful as in link juice wise? Or does this even sounds natural to you?

What is the best link building practice? (will there be a golden proportion for how many percentage of links should be towards home page, how many to detailed and how many to category for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any normal or natural link profile. In general most incoming links will go to the home page, but some sites will have large numbers of links to certain individual pages when they are very popular or go "viral".

It is most effective to get links to the pages that you want to rank - this may be category pages but is more likely to be your home page and individual articles.

Comment: Most of the links to my personal website are to my article pages

Comment: @John it really does depend on the site. Something a little more branded, like Stack Overflow for example, would likely get many more "mentions in passing" and thus more links to the home page than any individual question.

Comment: I completely agree